# TRY_PARSE vs TRY_CONVERT

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently studying for my MCSA Data Platform, I got the following question wrong and I was looking for an explanation as to why my answer was wrong as the in test explanation did not make much sense.

You have a table named AuditTrail that tracks modifications to data in other tables. The AuditTrail table is updated by many processes. Data input into AuditTrail may contain improperly formatted datetime values. You implement a process that retrieves data from various columns, but sometimes the process throws error when its unable to convert the data into valid date time values.
You need to convert the data into a valid date time value using the en-US format culture code. If the conversion fails, a null value must be returned in the en-US format culture code. If the conversion fails, a null value must be returned in the column output and the conversion process must not throw error.

The options were `TRY_PARSE` function vs `TRY_CONVERT` function.

I chose `TRY_PARSE` but the correct answer is `TRY_CONVERT`.

Can anybody clarify why `TRY_PARSE` is not a valid choice in this example as I do not want to make this mistake in the future

Comment: `try_parse()` with the culture argument seems appropriate.  I personally would choose `try_convert()` just because I am more familiar with it.

Comment: Yes, and I chose it just because the culture argument was specified in the question. Not sure why it is an incorrect option though.

Comment: That question seems very poorly worded at best and intentionally misleading / completely incorrect at worst. `TRY_CONVERT()` doesn't even allow you to specify a culture (only a style), and while they may correspond (e.g. style 101 and culture en-us), the question seems to be asking you to specify the culture code... So if anything, `TRY_PARSE()` is the only valid answer here (even though both options can achieve the same result).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation @ZLK. I hope they don't have such poorly worded questions in the final exam.

Comment: If I gave the answer you gave and they marked it as incorrect, I would complain considering it explicitly says you must do it `using the en-US format culture code`. There are even cases where try_convert would fail but try_parse would succeed... For example, the string `tuesday, 04/17/18` can be correctly parsed with try_parse (culture en-us), but it will return null with try_convert (any style afaik).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the main differences between `TRY_PARSE` and `TRY_CONVERT` is that `TRY_PARSE` accepts a culture with a `USING` clause.  Though poorly worded and wrapped in assumptions, this question seems to be suggesting that the input & system cultures are the same.

So in this case `TRY_CONVERT` would be the simpler of the two calls, since the default culture is assumed to be 'en-US'.

Had you needed to parse a french date from a string, the choice would have to be `TRY_PARSE`, since it allows you to specify the culture.

```
TRY_PARSE ('mars 18 2018' AS DATETIME USING 'fr-FR')
```

Source: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-parse-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1):

1. TRY_PARSE can only be used for converting from string to date/time
   or number data types where as TRY_CONVERT can be used for any
   general type conversions.   For example, you can use TRY_CONVERT to
   convert a string to XML data type, where as you can do the same
   using TRY_PARSE
2. Converting a string to XML data type using TRY_CONVERT

   SELECT TRY_CONVERT(XML, '') AS [XML]

> The above query produces the following
>
> ```
> XML     <root></child></root>
> ```

1. Converting a string to XML data type using TRY_PARSE

   SELECT TRY_PARSE('' AS XML) AS [XML]

> ```
> The above query will result in the following error
>   Invalid data type xml in function TRY_PARSE
> ```

- Another difference is TRY_PARSE relies on the presence of .the .NET
  Framework Common Language Runtime (CLR) where as TRY_CONVERT does
  not.